# Knockout & JQueryUI Drag - What is causing this element to not be draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to make a list item draggable in a project that is using Knockout.js.

I'm using the code below, and as you can see it is very simple:

```
<div id="room-view" >
    <ul data-bind="foreach: rooms">                     
        <li data-bind="text: name" class="draggable room-shape"></li>                   
    </ul>               
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    });
</script>
```

The list of 'room' renders just fine, but none of the items are draggable.  However, if I apply the 'draggable' class to any other element on the page - it becomes draggable.  Even if they are other list items.  The only difference is that these list items are being created through the 'foreach' binding.

Can anyone spot what may be causing this to not function correctly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`foreach` works by saving off a copy of the elements to use as the "template" whenever it needs to render an item.  So, the elements that you made draggable are not the ones that were rendered by `foreach`.

You could try to make sure that `draggable` is called after `applyBindings`, but that would only be effective if your `rooms` is not an observableArray that changes.  Any new items rendered would not be draggable.

Another option is to use the [afterRender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove) option to call `draggable` on your elements.

A better way is to use a custom binding.  It could be as simple as:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
   init: function(element) {
       $(element).draggable();
   }
};
```

or you can get into something a little better where you actually update an observableArray based on where your items are dropped.

I wrote an article a while back on it [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html).  With Knockout 2.0, I made a few changes to simplify the binding so that you can just use `sortableList` on the parent.

Here is a sample with just sortable: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/DVRVQ/

Here is a sample with dropping between lists: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sBHaP/

Comment: Ahhh, the dropping between lists sample is amazing - exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: This is amazingly simple still having a lot of control. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `draggable()` is applied when document is ready on *existing* elements. Knockout.js will modify the HTML and create new elements at the beginning and also when the `rooms` array is updated.

What you need is to enable dragging each time the  `room-view` is rendered. You can use [`afterRender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) for that.

Try this:

```
<div id="room-view" >
  <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: rooms, afterRender: afterRender }">                     
    <li data-bind="text: name" class="draggable room-shape"></li>                   
  </ul>               
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  // this is your already existing view-model that contains rooms, etc
  function roomsViewModel() {
    // ...

    // insert this in your view-model
    this.afterRender = function() {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new roomsViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is also extremely helpful - I wish I could mark 2 answers.

Comment: @PhillipKregg Hehe, thank you :). Ryan's answer is great and he is a Knockout.js celebrity, so he deserves to be the chosen one :P.